# Looking for a Banach space in which projection on a closed convex set is empty?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

It is well-known that projection on closed convex sets is nonempty in Hilbert spaces. I am interested in seeing a Banach space where the projection is empty on a closed convex set.

Definition of Projection of $x $ on set $C$:

$$   P_{C} (x) := \{ y \in C ~| ~ d(x , C ) = \|x -y\|  \}  $$

Comment: Could you please define "projection on a closed convex set"?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk

For example, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94928/219176

Comment: @hardmath Are you saying my question is not clear?

Comment: Thank you for the reference -- I don't understand your question, then. Since you are asking whether or not something is empty, I expect "projection on a closed convex set" to be a set. What set is it? The link you gave does not define any sets.

Comment: @hardmath I simply didn't define the "projection" for the same reason that I didn't define a convex set or a Hilbert space...

Comment: Imo, the definitions of "Hilbert space" and "convex set" are much more widely known than this definition of projection that you gave. Thanks for adding detail!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk  Sure. But I was not aware of the definition of Hilbert spaces two years ago but I knew the definition the projection since I took my first course in analysis. Maybe I don't belong to this world :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [projections in normed linear spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94928/projections-in-normed-linear-spaces)

Comment: No.  I'm interested in Banach spaces. The space in the link is not complete. @Ruy

Comment: Compare the notation $P_C(x)$ in this [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955327/projection-on-closed-convex-set), which defines the projection as a point (in the case the Banach space is *uniformly convex*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/82018/54637) solves your question. First, a small technicality: if $C$ is empty, it is a closed convex set such that all projections on $C$ are empty. This is technically a solution, but we want to exclude it.

Let $X$ be a non-reflexive Banach space (e.g. $\ell^1$). Let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous linear functional of norm $1$ on $X$ which does not attain a maximum on the closed unit ball of $X$ (e.g. $(x_n) \mapsto \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n-1}{n} x_n : \ell^1 \to \mathbb{R}$). Let $C = \{x \in X : f(x) = 1, \lVert x \rVert \leq 2\}$.

$C$ is closed and convex, since it is the intersection of the closed convex sets $f^{-1}(1)$ and $\{x \in X : \lVert x \rVert \leq 2\}$.

Since $\lVert f \rVert = \sup_{\lVert x \rVert = 1} \lvert f(x) \rvert = 1$, there is some $a \in X$ such that $f(a) = 1/2$ and $\lVert a \rVert \leq 1$. Then $2a \in C$, so $C$ is nonempty.

Now suppose for contradiction that $P_C(0)$ is nonempty; let $y \in P_C(0)$ -- in other words, $y \in C$ has minimal norm.

Since $f(y) = 1$, we have $y \neq 0$. Thus, let $z = \frac{1}{\lVert y \rVert} y$. Since $f$ does not attain a maximum on the unit ball, there exists some $z'$ such that $\lVert z' \rVert = 1$ and $f(z') > f(z)$. Now let $y' = \frac{1}{f(z')}z'$, so that $f(y') = 1$. Moreover,
$$\lVert y \rVert \leq 2 \implies f(z) = \frac{1}{\lVert y \rVert} f(y) = \frac{1}{\lVert y \rVert} \geq \frac{1}{2},$$
so
$$\lVert y' \rVert = \frac{1}{\lvert f(z') \rvert} \lVert z' \rVert = \frac{1}{f(z')} < \frac{1}{f(z)} \leq 2.$$
Thus, $y' \in C$. Finally,
$$\lVert y' \rVert = \frac{1}{\lvert f(z') \rvert} \lVert z' \rVert = \frac{1}{f(z')} < \frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\lVert y \rVert} f(y)} = \lVert y \rVert.$$
This contradicts the prior conclusion that $y \in C$ has minimal norm.